Как прописать автозаполнение $mail->addAddress
подскажите пожалуйста - как переписать форму отправки сообщений с $send_email на SMTP
<?
@session_start();
include('../connect/connect.php');
include('../lib/lib.php');

$id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);
if($id)
    {
    $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM board WHERE id='".$id."'");
    $rr=mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $email=$rr['email'];
    $zag=$rr['zag'];
    $them='Ответ на объявление N '.$id.': '.$zag;
    }
    
$idm=intval($_REQUEST['idm']);
if($idm)
    {
    $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magazin WHERE id='".$idm."'");
    $rr=mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $email=$rr['email'];
    $zag=$rr['zag'];
    $them='Сообщение для магазина '.$zag;
    }


if($_POST['Submit'])
    {
    if(!$_SESSION['ID_Glob'] && !$_SESSION['ID_P'])
        {
        $cap_a = trim($_POST['cap']);
        if(!$cap_a)
        $err .= 'Не указан защитный код<br>';
        else
            {
            if($_SESSION['real_code'] != $cap_a)
            $err .= 'Неверно указан защитный код<br>';
            else
                {
                $cap_a = number_format($cap_a,0,"",",");
                $cap_b = $_POST['ip_address'];
                if($cap_a!=$cap_b) $err .= 'Неверно указан защитный код<br>';
                }
            }
        if(isset($_SESSION['real_code'])) unset($_SESSION['real_code']);
        }
    
    
    $send_email=trim($_POST['send_email']);
    if(!$send_email)
    $err .= "Не указан e-mail<br>";
    elseif (! _email($send_email))
    $err .= "Некорректный e-mail<br>";
    
    
    $message1=_pre2($_POST['message']);
    $message=$message1[1];
    if(!$message)
    $err .= "Не указан текст сообщения<br>";
    
    if(!$err)
        {
        if (@mail_utf8($email, $them, $message, $send_email)) 
            $otpr='<font color=green>Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено</font> ';
        else
            {
            $otpr='<font color=red>Не удалось отправить Ваше сообщение<br>Попробуйте повторить позже</font> ';
            }
        }
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY>
<table width=100%>
    <tr height=64>
        <td width=64>
        <img border=0 src="../icon/8.gif">
        <td align=center><h3>Отправка сообщения</h3>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
    <?
    if($err)
    echo '<p><font color=red>'.$err.'</font></p>';
    
    if(!$otpr)
    {
    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <font size=+1 color=red>*</font> Ваш e-mail
    <br>
    <input size="30" type="text" name="send_email" value="<?=$send_email?>">
    <br>
    <font size=+1 color=red>*</font> Текст письма
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="9"><?=$message?></textarea>
    <br>
    <? 
    if(!$_SESSION['ID_Glob'] && !$_SESSION['ID_P'])
        {
        //$font_name[] = array(18, "../blok/new1.ttf"); 
        $font_name[] = array(18, "../blok/new2.ttf"); 
        //$font_name[] = array(20, "../blok/new3.ttf"); 
        //$font_name[] = array(22, "../blok/new4.ttf"); 
        shuffle($font_name);
    
        $m_rand1=1005;
        $m_rand2=9991;
        $cap_img='../tmp_capcha/'.ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'.jpg';
        @mt_srand(time());
        
            $cap_int=mt_rand($m_rand1,$m_rand2);
            $_SESSION['real_code']=$cap_int;
            if($typ_captcha && function_exists('cifr'))
            cifr($cap_int, $cap_img);
            else
                {
                $cap_str=code($cap_int);
                $im=imagecreate(470, 26);
                imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
                $color=imagecolorallocate($im,100,100,100);
                @imagettftext($im, $font_name[0][0], 0, 0, 19, $color, $font_name[0][1], $cap_str);
                imagejpeg($im, $cap_img);
                imagedestroy($im);
                }
        
        echo '<img border="0" src="'.$cap_img.'?id='.time().'">';
        ?>
        <br>
        <font size=+1 color=red>*</font> Введите защитный код цифрами 
        <input type="text" size=10 name="cap" id="cap" value="">
        <?
        }
        ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="ip_address" id="ip_address" value="<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>">
    <br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить" >
    </form>
    <?
    }
    else echo '<p>'.$otpr.'</p>';
    ?>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/tb.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
        

Как совместить с кодом SMTP ?
`$mail->isSMTP();// Настройте почтовую программу на использование SMTP
$mail->Host = 'ssl://mail.smtp';  // Укажите SMTP-сервер
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // Включить аутентификацию SMTP
$mail->Username = 'ytre@reds.ru';  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '24321567/yt2kj'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // Включить шифрование, «ssl» 

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = ('?????????');
$mail->addAddress('??????');  // Добавить получателя

$mail->Subject = 'Вот тема';
$mail->Body    = 'Это текст сообщения HTML <b>выделен жирным шрифтом!</b>';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Сообщение не может быть отправлено.';
    echo 'Ошибка почтовой программы: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Сообщение отправлено';
}`

Хотя бы подскажите как прописать автозаполнение -
$mail->From = ('?????????');
$mail->addAddress('??????');

Буду очень благодарен за любую подсказку
Коды по отдельности работают, переписать mysql на mysqli, это я знаю как, исправлю сам.
$mail->AddAddress ($send_email=trim($_POST['send_email']));

Много варианотов пробовал, но всё ошибки.
